# Python read a text file

Tags: python

I am writing some code for my OCR GCSE project on Python.

Task 13a states:

Write a program that reads a list of numbers from a file then outputs the average.
So if your file contained
3
45
83
21
Your program would output: 38

So far, I know all the other code, apart from the code that opens the text file and reads the numbers.

After spending 30 or so minutes researching, I sort of got it to work, but I really need some help.

Any suggestions/code/comments are welcome :)

Comment: If you have something that sort of works, where is your code? What is the problem with it?

Comment: jj1064, what type of file are you saving your data in? What is your current code? Your post doesn't give us much room to find a solution.

Comment: If you got it working then what help do you need? You need to post specific issue with what you have tried so far

Comment: *"...I sort of got it to work..."*, What's the problem then?

Comment: I don't have that code at the moment as it is stored on a flash drive

Answer (score 0):

People around here don't like when you mention it's help for homework. This solution reads the file a byte at a time. This was mostly a fun excuse to use a stream-processing average calculation. Presumably, this should be very memory efficient.

```
def new_avg(avg, x, n):
    return float((avg * n + x) / (n + 1))

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    num, avg, n = "", 0, 0
    for i in iter(lambda: file.read(1), ""):
        if i == " ":
            avg = new_avg(avg, int(num), n)
            num = ""
            n += 1
        else:
            num += i
    avg = new_avg(avg, int(num), n)
    print(avg)
```

Comment: There is no problem in helping someone with their homework. But "This is my homework, do it for me plz" questions will be down voted into oblivion.

Comment: I actually didn't realize there were specific guidelines for this, thanks

Comment: You can find more about it on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    t = f.readline().split(' ')
print(sum(t)/len(t))
```

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In particular, homework questions are required to include the OP's efforts and where s/he has encountered difficulty in that context.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file you can use -

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r') as cards:
```

Then to create a list containing all lines you can use -

```
file = file.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
```

Remember to close the file when you are finished

```
file.close()
```